# response function and Fourier transform

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, causality

A response function defined as the kernel of the  following integral:

$\rho(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t \chi(t,t') E(t')dt'$ (1), where $\chi(t,t')$ is the response function.

Physically, it relates perturbation $E(t')$ to a system's response $\rho(t)$. For example, it can be the electric field and the charge density of the system. The lower limit in the integral is $-\infty$ indicates that the response of a system cannot be instant and depends on all **previous** times and the upper limit is simply the present time.

However, using Fourier transform one can derive eq. (1) and get the upper limit $+\infty$.

One can start with the relation in the frequency space: $\rho(\omega) = \chi(\omega)E(\omega)$ and then taking the inverse Fourier transform get this:

$\rho(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-i\omega t) d\omega \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \chi(t')\exp(i\omega t) dt'\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} E(t'') \exp(i\omega t'')dt''  $ 
And after playing with the integral we get this:

$\rho(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \chi(t-t')E(t')dt'$

So now the system's response depends also on all future times (the upper limit is $+\infty$). Physically, it doesn't make sense to me. Can someone clarify it? What about the causality then?

Answer (score 4):

Causality requires that $\chi(t) \propto \Theta(t)$, where $\Theta(t)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). In other words, $\chi(t-t') = 0$ for $t'>t$, so that only past influences from times $t'\leq t$ affect the system response at time $t$. This leads to constraints on $\chi(\omega)$ viewed as a function of complex frequency: it must be analytic in the upper half plane. The Wikipedia page on [Kramers-Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations) contains more information.